# "I'm proud that you are my father"

Tags: expression-choice

A friend wrote this as a tribute to her father for his birthday:

> I'm proud that you are my father

I am not a native speaker either, but it to me it sounds like "you are the father of someone great so you must be great".

Or does it sound OK?

Comment: It's fine as is, but if you're bothered that your father might misunderstand you (?!), just say *"I'm proud **of you as** my father"*, or *"I'm proud **to have you as** my father"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, I see nothing wrong either with the sentence as written, though I would suspect it more common for the sentence to take the opposite perspective:

> I am proud to be your daughter/son

In either case you would be proud of his personality or his achievements in life.
Of course such achievements might be simply having other great children, however it would be far nearer to be proud of him for something else/more.

Comment: You could also say, "I'm proud to have you as my father." I think that is more idiomatic, and keeps the focus on him not you :)

Oh, wait, I see, FumbleFingers already said that, above. I think "I'm proud of you as my father," is less idiomatic though. As a native English speaker, I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 5):

As a native BE speaker I can confirm that the phrase is fine as stated, conveying the sense that 'I am proud *of the fact* that you are my father.'

Comment: Thanks - two nations separated by a common language, eh?

Comment: "the fact that" is generally an unnecessary phrase. It doesn't really add anything to the sentence's meaning here, or in other cases. (See my comment above for a better suggestion, imo.)

Answer (score 1):

The sentence as given carries no implication of "you're great because of your children" to me, nor do I think any native English speaker would be likely to interpret it that way. To give that idea you would have to say something more like, "You should be proud to be my father".